# "Trito" versus "tritato"

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, cooking

Ho letto queste due parole col significato di "ridotto in frammenti minuti", comunque non sono sicura se ci sia alcuna differenza di uso tra questi vocaboli. Sapreste dirmi qualcosa al riguardo? Ad esempio, nel contesto di una ricetta di cucina, cosa dovrei scrivere:

- "erbe aromatiche *trite*"
- o "erbe aromatiche *tritate*"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Credo che la differenza sia sottile e banale, ma spesso trascurata. Andando a vedere le voci sul vocabolario Treccani ([tritare](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/tritare/) e [trito](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/trito/)), risulta che "trito" è *aggettivo*, mentre "tritato" è *participio passato* con possibilità di essere usato come aggettivo o addirittura come *sostantivo*.

Quindi, prendendo l'esempio della ricetta:

- Se vuoi indicare che le erbe devono essere precedentemente lavorate da chi fruisce della ricetta, a mio avviso è meglio usare *tritate*.
- Se vuoi indicare che le erbe sono già state lavorate in un contesto esterno, è meglio usare *trite*.
- Nel caso tu voglia usare un altro formato, puoi scrivere di usare un *tritato* di erbe.

In generale, non dovrebbe esserci prevalenza nell'utilizzo di uno o dell'altro, tranne nel caso di sostantivo dove *tritato* risulta essere l'unica opzione.

Comment: Dunque, se ho capito bene, si potrebbe anche dire "un tritato di erbe aromatiche"?

Comment: Esatto, avresti anche questa possibilità! La aggiungo alla risposta, anche se credo che il tuo dubbio fosse sugli aggettivi!

Comment: @Charo Nota che "trito" (spesso associato con "ritrito", a enfatizzare il concetto) si usa anche per indicare una cosa vecchia e già nota che viene ripresentata, come in "La lezione è stata piena di argomenti triti e ritriti".